# Domain name rejected by nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, nginx

I have a server running a very simple rails app. It has `nginx` set up to listen on port `80`, which further forwards the request to a `unicorn` socket file under `(Rails.root)/tmp/unicorn.sock`.

I bought a domain name from domain.com and pointed it to my server's address=.

e.g.

```
Domain: mydomain.com -> Server: 110.56.45.12
```

Everything works great when I hit the server directly, by either visiting `110.56.45.12` in my browser or `ssh`-ing into the box and running `curl 127.0.0.1`. I assume this is because both these actions hit port `80` and `nginx` serves back the correct content.

However when I try to use the public domain name `domain.com` or I try `curl localhost` I get the classic "We're sorry, but something went wrong." rails page.

I checked the rails `production` log and there is nothing there. I then checked `nginx` error log at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and only got

```
2015/05/27 07:01:24 [error] 20041#0: *143 connect() to unix:/home/jeeves/my_app/tmp/unicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/jeeves/my_app/tmp/unicorn.sock:/", host: "localhost"
```

Is there any reason my server is rejecting that connection?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's my `nginx.conf` file

```
user  jeeves;
worker_processes  1;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay off;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_min_length 500;
    gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css
      text/comma-separated-values text/javascript
      application/x-javascript application/atom+xml;

    ##
    # Unicorn Rails
    ##

    upstream unicorn {  
      server unix:/home/jeeves/my_app/tmp/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }

    ##
    # Includes
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

The last line includes everything in the `sites-enabled` directory, which is only one file - `mydomain.com`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com; # Replace this with your site's domain.

  keepalive_timeout 300;

  client_max_body_size 4G;

  # Set this to the public folder location of your Rails application.
  root /home/jeeves/my_app/public; 

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @unicorn;

  location @unicorn {
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_Proto $scheme;
          proxy_redirect off;
          # This passes requests to unicorn, as defined in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          proxy_pass http://unicorn;
          proxy_read_timeout 300s;
          proxy_send_timeout 300s;
  }

  # You can override error pages by redirecting the requests to a file in your
  # application's public folder, if you so desire:
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
}
```

Comment: can you show nginx config? do you have upstream server defined in  the config?

Comment: @Stugal - I edited my post to include my `ngingx` config files. I do have `updatream` defined, it points to the `unicorn` socket connected to my rails app `my_app`. Thanks!